# Trying to relate two collections getting an input value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to relate two collections on meteor sure using mongodb, well my solution was print a value on  a input and then get that value and do and specific find on the other collection and boom magically be related, i know kind of basic but is all i can do i guess right?, so well my issue is that when i try to   get this input value always is the same, it seems like there is an issue on the helper idk, this is de code where i'm trying to get de input value, is on a rendered template

```
el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
                overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
                overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
          Tracker.autorun(function(){
            valueInputCliente  = $("#inputCliente").val();
            Session.set("valorInput",valueInputCliente)
            console.log("el valor del input es " + valueInputCliente);
          });
                if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                    }, 25 );
                }
            });

close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
       Tracker.autorun(function(){
         var valorInput = Session.get("valorInput")
         valorInput  = $("#inputCliente").empty();
          console.log("el valor del input ahora es " + valorInput)
       });
                ev.stopPropagation();
                removeModalHandler();
            });
```

So in this fuction when someone open the element the input should be got, and then when close the element the value is empy, but just works with the first value of mongo, so i hope have been clear and you could help me, sorry for my english i do my best.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure, I understood everything and get your problem. But still I have some remarks and maybe a solution.

First if you are using meteor, why don't you use the meteor way of thinking events, I mean you put some click events on two elements with JavaScript but in meteor you can bind them with a template like this :

```
Template.mytemplate.events({
    'click el':function(e){
        //do stuff
    },
    'click close':function(e){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

But the problem is not here.
Secondly, you are using Tracker.autorun(...) in your first event handler. So you wan to re-run that function when a dependency changes. But i cannot see one reactive data sources inside your Tracker.aurtorun function. 
If I understand the docs right :

> Tracker.autorun allows you to run a function that depends on reactive data sources, in such a way that if there are changes to the data later, the function will be rerun.

You need a reactive data source to rerun your function,

```
valueInputCliente  = $("#inputCliente").val();
```

is not, I cannot find the code to make this a reactive data source. (but it is possible)
And Session.set is not either (But Session.get is !).
[session docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session)

So maybe here is your problem, this function is not rerun. So you second event handler, which is ok because it depends of a reactive data source :

```
var valorInput = Session.get("valorInput")
```

will not be rerun either because the valorInput is not changed more than once (the first time).

So you need to put a reactive data source in your first handler to trigger your function when you need it. I am not sure I responded your very problem, but hope it helps !

Comment: Hey bro i really appreciate your explanation actually i tried with events and idk maybe there is something wrong on the logic about the reactive data source like you said, thank you!